# How to Cancel/Delete a scheduled Calendly event (linked with google meet), which should also be removed from google calendar?

Tags: google-calendar-api, cancellation, google-meet, calendly

I tried looking at the developer [docs](https://developer.calendly.com/api-docs/ZG9jOjQ1Mg-calendly-developer).

One specific API which caught my eye: https://developer.calendly.com/api-docs/b3A6Mzc3OTc1OTc-delete-invitee-no-show
This marks the invitee as "no show" and it doesn't free up the calendar of the organizer.

Answer (score 3):

**NEW**

Calendly's public api now supports [canceling an event](https://developer.calendly.com/api-docs/afb2e9fe3a0a0-cancel-event).

**OLD**

Calendly does not currently provide a public api to cancel an existing event. To cancel the event without using Calendly's UI you would need to use the [Google Calendar api to delete the event](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/v3/reference/events/delete).

If you have the **Sync cancellations** feature enabled in Calendly then deleting the Google calendar event will cause the event to also be canceled in Calendly.

[image]

Comment: The "Old" way of doing this is still supported and works well for me because I'm managing events via Google Calendar. You can find this checkbox by going to Account > Calendar Connections and editing the "Add to calendar connection. I'm trying to edit the post to include this information, but the queue is full right now.

Answer (score 0):

So, I asked this question to their support and got the following response.

> At this time, there is not an API endpoint that supports canceling or rescheduling a scheduled event, however, the cancel and reschedule URLs are on the [Invitee Resource](https://calendly.stoplight.io/docs/api-docs/reference/calendly-api/openapi.yaml/paths/%7E1scheduled_events%7E1%7Buuid%7D%7E1invitees/get).

> The cancel and reschedule URL are on the v2 API webhook payload as well. You can see an example of the [payload here](https://calendly.stoplight.io/docs/api-docs/c2NoOjIxNDU0NTQ2-webhook-payload).
> These URLs are always inserted at the bottom of calendar events or email confirmations, but they are available on the API to be more easily retrievable.

You can invoke `PUT` API
[https://calendly.com/api/booking/cancellations/{invitee_uuid}](https://calendly.com/api/booking/cancellations/%7Binvitee_uuid%7D)
with request body

```
"cancellation": {
    "cancel_reason": "reason text",
    "canceled_by": "",
}
```

**Please understand that this API can change any time without any notice.**

[image: sample payload]

Answer (score 0):

You could use [this endpoint](https://developer.calendly.com/api-docs/b3A6NDIzMTg0NDc-cancel-event), doesn't it work for you?
Maybe it's a new endpoint, I haven't seen it there a few days ago.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Seems like they recently introduced this.